# c# WPF DataGrid - writing cell values row by row into xml File

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, datagrid, creation

### Problem Description:

I have a **DataGrid**. It is being populated by a **List**. The code for that is as follows:

```
List<SomeClass> someClassList = new List<SomeClass>();
//Fill somClassList with data (omited for brevity)
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = someClassList;
```

This *works* and all the values are showing up correctly. The user can *edit* all cells now and create new rows. After the user clicks some button I want to *save* the *values* inside that **DataGrid** into a **XML-File** of the following structure:

```
<Root>
    <a>
        <b>val1</b>
        <c>val2</c>
        <d>
            <e>
                <f>val3</f>
                <g>val4</g>
                <h>val5</h>
                <i>val6</i>
            </e>
            <!--variable number of 'e'- tags with inner structure as above-->
        </d>
     </a>
     <!--variable number of 'a'-tags with inner structure as above-->
</Root>
```

For this reason I have decided that it would be clever if I **iterated over the DataGrid row by row**. Therefore the Button-Click-event-Handler contains code  that *performs an iteration* (every *value is reproduced by the WriteLine()*-method):

```
foreach (SomeClass someClassElement in myDataGrid.ItemsSource)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(someClassElement.b+ ", " + someClassElement.c+ ", " +
                    someClassElement.f + ", " + someClassElement.g + ", " +
                    someClassElement.h + ", " + someClassElement.i);
}
```

I have to *write each line into an **XML-file** now.* Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be a trivial task, because there are **two inner-tags with variable number of occurences**.

What I got so far is the following **code**, which produces the likewise appended **XML-File** from an **example DataGrid** that I added for the purpose of clarity.

```
//Button click code
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode myRoot = doc.CreateElement("Root");
XmlNode a,b,c,d,e;
String last_b_value = "0";
foreach (SomeClass someClassElement in myDataGrid.ItemsSource)
{
    String current_b_value = someClassElement.b;
    if (last_b_value != current_b_value)
    {
        //Creating XML-elements and setting text
        a = doc.CreateElement("a");
        b = doc.CreateElement("b");
        b.InnerText = someClassElement.b;
        c = doc.CreateElement("c");
        c.InnerText = someClassElement.c;
        d = doc.CreateElement("d");
        e = doc.CreateElement("e");

        a.AppendChild(b);
        a.AppendChild(c);
        a.AppendChild(d);
        d.AppendChild(e);
    }
}
doc.AppendChild(myRoot);
// Save document
string filename = dlg.FileName;
doc.Save(@filename);
```

Here is the outputted XML-file:

```
<root>
  <a>
    <b>val_1_1</b>
    <c>val_1_2</c>
    <d>
      <e />
      <!-- the varying number of 'e'-tags is not created correctly -->
    </d>
  </a>
  <a>
    <b>val_2_1</b>
    <c>val_2_2</c>
    <d>
      <e />
      <!-- the varying number of 'e'-tags is not created correctly -->
    </d>
  </a>
  <a>
     <b>val_3_1</b>
     <c>val_3_2</c>
     <d>
       <e />
       <!-- the varying number of 'e'-tags is not created correctly -->
     </d>
  </a>
  <!-- number of varying 'a'-tags is created correctly -->
</root>
```

And here is the *example*-**DataGrid** from which the XML-File is created after the user clicks the button:

[image: example-Datagrid]

The code **does appropriately handle** the *variable number of 'a'- tags*, but **lacks the functionality** to *write the also varying number of 'e'-tags* inside each 'a'-tag.

Instead the output **XML-file should look like**:

```
<Root>
  <a>
    <b>val_1_1</b>
    <c>val_1_2</c>
    <d>
          <e>
          <f>x1</f>
          <g>x1</g>
          <h>x1</h>
          <i>x1</i>
      </e>
      <e>
          <f>x2</f>
          <g>x2</g>
          <h>x2</h>
          <i>x2</i>
      </e>
      <e>
          <f>x3</f>
          <g>x3</g>
          <h>x3</h>
          <i>x3</i>
      </e>
    </d>
  </a>
  <a>
    <b>val_2_1</b>
    <c>val_2_2</c>
    <d>
      <e>
          <f>x4</f>
          <g>x4</g>
          <h>x4</h>
          <i>x4</i>
      </e>
      <e>
          <f>x5</f>
          <g>x5</g>
          <h>x5</h>
          <i>x5</i>
      </e>
    </d>
  </a>
  <a>
    <b>val_3_1</b>
    <c>val_3_2</c>
    <d>
      <e>
          <f>x6</f>
          <g>x6</g>
          <h>x6</h>
          <i>x6</i>
      </e>
    </d>
  </a>
</Root>
```

### Questions:

1. How can I adapt the code to create the missing 'e'-tags ?
2. Is there a smarter way to read the **DataGrid** and save its values into the same structured XML-file?

Comment: Serialize your objects using an XMLSerializer. I strongly suggest you avoid trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Regarding your question #2, _C# In-Depth_ by Jon Skeet has a nice desciption of how to use Linq to write XML.  I was reading it just last night.  I do not recall the details at the moment and am away from the book -- thus a comment but not an actual answer.

Comment: The problem with XMLSerializer is, that the varying length of the 'e'-tags inside the 'a'-tags are also not handled.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple answer to **Question 1**:

I had to adapt the if clause to the following to have the XML-output structured correctly:

```
  //Button click code
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  XmlNode myRoot = doc.CreateElement("Root");
  XmlNode a,b,c,d,e;
  String last_b_value = "0";
  foreach (SomeClass someClassElement in myDataGrid.ItemsSource)
  {
   String current_b_value = someClassElement.b;
   if (last_b_value != current_b_value)
   {
       //Creating XML-elements and setting text
       a = doc.CreateElement("a");
       b = doc.CreateElement("b");
       b.InnerText = someClassElement.b;
       c = doc.CreateElement("c");
       c.InnerText = someClassElement.c;
       d = doc.CreateElement("d");
       e = doc.CreateElement("e");


   }else if(last_b_value == current_b_value){
       e = doc.CreateElement("e");
   }
       a.AppendChild(b);
       a.AppendChild(c);
       a.AppendChild(d);
       d.AppendChild(e);
  }
  doc.AppendChild(myRoot);
  // Save document
  string filename = dlg.FileName;
  doc.Save(@filename);
```

With the if-clause structured this way, the abcd-tags are omitted.